# CoPilot Truck HD, USA & Canada Maps App Open URL Schema for iOS iPhone SDK

Tags: ios4, ios5, openurl

I am trying to open the CoPilot Truck HD, USA & Canada Maps app from my own app that I am writing.  This is the URL for the app on iTunes

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/copilot-truck-hd-north-america/id399782003?mt=8

I know TomTom and Google Maps has this feature and was wondering if anyone knows if this app does and what the open URL statement is? to send an address to the app to begin a new route.

thanks for your help